# nginx clean forward rewrite multiple similar domains

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have around 50 identical domains names with different tld like: domain.net, domain.org, domain.de, domain.biz, domain.ca... now I would like to forward all incoming requests to this domain with and without www on nginx to: http://domain.com how I can do this without need to list every domain?

Something like: forward all request to *.domain.* or domain.* to: http://domain.com permanent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nginx [server_name](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_name) directive with wildcards. Example:

```
server { 
  server_name domain.com; 

  ... real server ...
}

server { 
  server_name domain.* www.domain.*; 
  rewrite ^ $scheme://domain.com$request_uri? permanent; 
}
```

Comment: The order doesn't matter for the reason you stated.  Wildcard server name entries are only checked if no exact match is [found](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_name).  However, it does matter if no server_name matches, in which case you may want the order reversed, so the redirecting server would still redirect to the desired name.  The answer is still a good one, but you should probably remove that comment.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I've missed the fact that static names matched before wildcard domains. I've removed this misleading comment.

Answer (score 0):

I never checked using a catch all tld but its worth a try. Don't have access to any nginx install right now, so if you can try the following do let me know too if it worked or not.

```
server {

            listen   80;
            server_name  domain.* *.domain.*;
            rewrite ^/(.*) http://domain.com/$1 permanent;

}
```